# To prove $\sum_{k=0}^{2016}\frac{1}{2017\zeta_{k}-1}=\frac{2017}{2017^{2017}-1}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers, summation, roots-of-unity

To prove
$$\sum_{k=0}^{2016}\left(\zeta_k\prod_{~~~~~~j\neq k,\\ 0\leq j\leq 2016}(2017-\zeta_j)\right)=2017,$$
where $\zeta_0,\zeta_1,\cdots,\zeta_{2016}$ are the $2017$-th roots of the unity.

Alternatively, to show
$$\sum_{k=0}^{2016}\frac{1}{2017\zeta_{k}-1}=\frac{2017}{2017^{2017}-1}$$
It can be proven by residue theorem. However, is there an elementary proof?

Comment: @Mercury: why make this a comment rather than an answer?

Comment: For the second part, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2209034/finding-sum-k-0n-1-dfrac-alpha-k2-alpha-k-where-alpha-k-is-prim and linked posts therein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first formulation, consider
$$f(x):=x^n-1=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(x-\zeta_k).$$
We have
$$nx^{n-1}=f'(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\prod_{j\neq k}(x-\zeta_j),$$
So
$$n=xf'(x)-nf(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(x\prod_{j\neq k}(x-\zeta_j)-\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}(x-\zeta_j)\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\zeta_k\prod_{j\neq k}(x-\zeta_j).$$

---

For the alternative one, note that the roots of $f(x):=x^n-1$ are $\zeta_0,\ldots,\zeta_{n-1}$, so the roots of
$$g(x):=n^nf\left(\frac{x+1}{n}\right)=(x+1)^n-n^n=x^n+\ldots+nx+(1-n^n)$$
are $n\zeta_0-1,\ldots,n\zeta_{n-1}-1$. Then by Vieta's formulas
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n\zeta_k-1}=-\frac{n}{1-n^n}=\frac{n}{n^n-1}.$$
This gives another proof.