Quadratic Equation whose roots are $\alpha$ and $\beta$
Quadratic Equation whose roots are $\alpha$ and $\beta$

It is given that roots of $(a+b+c)x^2+(b+2c)x+c=0$ are
$\frac{\alpha}{\alpha -1}$ and $\frac{\beta}{\beta -1}$.

Now we have to find the quadratic equation whose roots are $\alpha$ and $\beta$ without finding $\alpha + \beta$ and $\alpha \beta$.
I took

$x=\frac{\alpha}{\alpha -1}$
then it yeilds $\alpha=\frac{x}{x -1}$.

Now $\alpha $ must be a root of the equation we must determine.
$$A\alpha^2+B\alpha+C=0$$
How can I find $A,B,C ?$ Is there a method other than this ?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2487783/let-alpha-beta-are-the-roots-of-3x2x5-0

Hint: $\alpha,\beta$ are roots of the polynomial $(z-1)^2f(\frac{z}{z-1})$ where $f(z) = (a+b+c)z^2 + (b+2c)z+c$.

The simplest second-degree equation, having $\frac{\alpha}{\alpha - 1}$ and $\frac{\beta}{\beta - 1}$ as roots, is:
$$(x - \frac{\alpha}{\alpha - 1}) \cdot (x - \frac{\beta}{\beta - 1}) = 0$$
This can be re-written as:
$$x^2 - (\frac{\alpha}{\alpha - 1} + \frac{\beta}{\beta - 1}) \cdot x + \left( \frac{\alpha}{\alpha - 1} \cdot \frac{\beta}{\beta - 1} \right) = 0$$
You claim that the coefficient of $x^2$ should be equal to $a+b+c$, so the equation becomes:
$$(a+b+c) \cdot x^2 - (a+b+c) \cdot(\frac{\alpha}{\alpha - 1} + \frac{\beta}{\beta - 1}) \cdot x + (a+b+c) \cdot \frac{\alpha}{\alpha - 1} \cdot \frac{\beta}{\beta - 1} = 0$$
This comes down to:

$(a+b+c) \cdot(\frac{\alpha}{\alpha - 1} + \frac{\beta}{\beta - 1}) = b + 2c$
$(a+b+c) \cdot \frac{\alpha}{\alpha - 1} \cdot \frac{\beta}{\beta - 1} = c$

From here, it's just calculating.

You can plug in $x=\frac{\alpha}{\alpha -1}$ into the initial equation, which is a root by assumption.
$(a+b+c)x^2+(b+2c)x+c=0$
$\Leftrightarrow (a+b+c)\alpha ^2 + (b+2c)\alpha (\alpha - 1) + c (\alpha - 1)^2 = 0$
$\Leftrightarrow (a+2b+4c)\alpha ^2 - (b+4c)\alpha  +c = 0$
So $\alpha$ is a root of $(a+2b+4c)X ^2 - (b+4c)X+c $
Since the problem is symmetric in $\alpha $ and $\beta$, we know that $\beta$ will also satisfy the above polynomial.
By symmetric I mean that you can replace $\alpha$ by $\beta$ in the above calculation and nothing will change.

You multiplied with $(\alpha-1)^2$ in the second row. It must be $(a+b+c)\alpha^2+(b+2c)\alpha(\alpha-1)+c(\alpha-1)^2 = 0$
