# Roots of Unity Questions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, contest-math, roots-of-unity

Let $\ w = e^{\frac{4\pi i}{7}}$. Evaluate $(2+w)(2+w^2)(2+w^3)(2+w^4)(2+w^5)(2+w^6)$.

How would you evaluate the expression using the concepts of Roots of Unity or other methods?

Comment: Hint: can you factor the polynomial $x^7 + 1$, one of whose roots is $-w$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $w$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity then
$$x^n-1=(x-1)(x-w)(x-w^2)\cdots(x-w^{n-1}).\tag1$$
Here $w$ is a primitive seventh root of unity, and you seek
$$(2+w)(2+w^2)\cdots(2+w^6).\tag2$$
In $(2)$ you have six factors, not seven as in $(1)$ and plus
rather than minus signs, but there is a value of $x$ you can choose in $(1)$ to give you something close enough to $(2)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$w^7=1$$

Clearly, the roots of $$x^7-1=0$$ are $w^r,0\le r\le6$

Let $2+x=y\implies0=(y-2)^7-1=y^7-\binom71y^62^1+\cdots-(2^7+1)$

$$\implies\prod_{r=0}^6(2+w^r)=\dfrac{2^7+1}1$$

What is $2+w^0=?$

Comment: See also : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2209034/finding-sum-k-0n-1-dfrac-alpha-k2-alpha-k-where-alpha-k-is-prim