# Evaluating the complex summation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> $1,z_1,z_2,z_3,...z_{n-1}$ are the $n^{\text{th}}$ roots of unity, then the value of $\dfrac 1{3-z_1}+ \dfrac{1}{3-z_2}+...+\dfrac 1 {3-z_{n-1}}$ is equal to?

I wrote the polar form of the $n$th root of unity $(\cos \dfrac{2k\pi}{n}+i \sin\dfrac{ 2k\pi}{n})$ $\forall ~ k\in\{0,1,2...n-1\} $

But that didn't help at all. How do I go about solving this problem?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2209034/finding-sum-k-0n-1-dfrac-alpha-k2-alpha-k-where-alpha-k-is-prim and related ones like https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1811081/problem-based-on-sum-of-reciprocal-of-nth-roots-of-unity

Comment: You know that $f(z) = z^n - 1 = (z-z_1)\cdots (z-z_{n})$ (with $z_n = 1$) and note that $f'(z)/f(z) = \sum \frac{1}{z-z_i}$

Answer (score 3):

If a polynomial $q(z)$ is such that
$$ q(z)=\prod_{k=1}^{n}(z-\zeta_k) $$
then by applying $\frac{d}{dz}\log(\cdot)$ to both sides we get
$$ \frac{q'(z)}{q(z)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{z-\zeta_k} $$
hence your sum is just $\frac{n z^{n-1}}{z^n-1}$ evaluated at $z=3$, i.e. ${\frac{n 3^{n-1}}{3^n-1}}$, minus the contribution due to $\zeta_1=1$.

Comment: What does that symbol before $k$ mean? How to read it?

Comment: @Abcd its a greek alphabet zeta. Its nothing but root of $q$ here.

Comment: How did you find that sum is $$\frac {nz^{n-1}}{z^n-1}$$

Comment: @Manthanein: $z^n-1$ is the polynomial vanishing at the $n$-th roots of unity and $\frac{d}{dz}(z^n-1)=n z^{n-1}$.

Comment: Oh got that thanks (+1)

Answer (score 2):

For $k=1,2,\dots n-1$, $z_k^n=1$. Let $\displaystyle y_k=\frac{1}{3-z_k}$.

$$\left(3-\frac{1}{y_k}\right)^n=z_k^n=1$$

$$(3y_k-1)^n=y_k^n$$

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}, y_1,y_2,\dots,y_{n-1}$ are the roots of $(3y-1)^n-y^n=0$.

$$\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}y_k=\frac{n\cdot 3^{n-1}}{3^n-1}$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}y_k=\frac{n\cdot 3^{n-1}}{3^n-1}-\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: It's a typo. It should be $(3y_k-1)^n=y_k^n$. It comes from $y_k^n(3-\frac{1}{y_k})^n=y_k^n$

Comment: How did you get 1/2 as a root and how did you transform $y_k$ to $y$?

Comment: $1$ is a $n$-th root of unity. So $y_0=\frac{1}{3-1}$ should also be a root of $(3y-1)^n=y^n$.

Comment: If you want to check whether $y_k$ is a root of $(3y-1)^n=y^n$, you just substitute $y$ by $y_k$ to see whether the equality holds. Of course, it does, as $(3y_k-1)^n=y_k^n$.for all $k$.

Comment: I don't get why you included $1/2$ explicitly...

Comment: As in the question, $1,z_1,z_2,\dots,z_{n-1}$ are the roots of unity. $1$ is one of the roots of $z^n=1$. So naturally, $\frac{1}{3-1}$ is a root of $(3y-1)^n=y^n$.  You may take $z_0=1$, then $\frac{1}{2}$ is just $y_0$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74517/discussion-between-abcd-and-cy-aries).