# Find $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2-a^i}$ if $1,a,a^2,...,a^{n-1}$ are the n$^\text{th}$ roots of unity

Tags: complex-numbers, roots, roots-of-unity

> If $1,a,a^2,...,a^{n-1}$ are the n$^\text{th}$ roots of unity, then prove that$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2-a^i}=\frac{(n-2)2^{n-1}+1}{2^n-1}$$

$$
\alpha_r=e^{i\tfrac{2\pi r}{n}}=a^{r-1}\\
x^n=1\implies x^n-1=(x-1)(x-a)(x-a^2)...(x-a^{n-1})=0
$$

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2-a^i}=\frac{1}{2-a}+\frac{1}{2-a^2}+\frac{1}{2-a^3}+....+\frac{1}{2-a^{n-1}}\\
=
$$
**Note:** This is solved using derivative of logarithm in [Problem based on sum of reciprocal of ℎ roots of unity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1811081/problem-based-on-sum-of-reciprocal-of-nth-roots-of-unity) which is good, but I am looking for more of a direct and easier way to find the solution.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1909362/product-of-one-minus-the-tenth-roots-of-unity/1909366#1909366  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1811081/problem-based-on-sum-of-reciprocal-of-nth-roots-of-unity

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_i=\frac{1}{2-a_i}$.

Thus, $$a_i=2-\frac{1}{x_i},$$ which says that $x_i$ they are roots of the equation:
$$\left(2-\frac{1}{x_i}\right)^n-1=0$$ or
$$(2x_i-1)^n-x_i^n=0$$ or
$$(2^n-1)x_i^n-n2^{n-1}x_i^{n-1}+...=0,$$ which gives
$$x_1+x_2+...+x_n=\frac{n2^{n-1}}{2^n-1}.$$
Thus, $$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2-a^i}=\frac{n2^{n-1}}{2^n-1}-1=\frac{(n-2)2^{n-1}+1}{2^n-1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

I'll do $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}1/(2-a^i)$ instead:
\begin{align}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac1{2-a^i}&=\frac12\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac1{1-a^i/2}
=\frac12\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{a^{ik}}{2^k}
=\frac12\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{a^{ik}}{2^k}\\
&=\frac 12\sum_{l=0}^\infty\frac{n}{2^{nl}}=\frac{n}{2(1-2^{-n})}
=\frac{n2^{n-1}}{2^n-1}.
\end{align}

Comment: i am having trouble understand ur method. could u pls explain each steps ?